# Primefaces 6 pie chart export not working in Safari

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I am exporting Primefaces pie chart as the following:

```
        <p:panel header="My Report" closable="true" toggleable="true">
        <p:chart type="pie" widgetVar="pie"
                 model="#{mybean.pieChartModel}"
                 style="height: 700px; width: 1000px"
                 styleClass="center"/>

        <p:dialog widgetVar="pieDlg" showEffect="fade" modal="true" header="My Chart">
            <p:outputPanel id="pieOut" layout="block" />
        </p:dialog>

        <p:commandLink  id="export" onclick="exportPieChart();">
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/export.png"/>
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:tooltip for="export"  value="Export Chart" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"/>
    </p:panel>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exportPieChart() {
            //export image
            $('#pieOut').empty().append(PF('pie').exportAsImage());
            //show the dialog
            PF('pieDlg').show();
        }
    </script>
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome. But not in Chrome and Safari.

Firefox log message :

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

The same code works fine for exporting bar charts.

Used platforms:
JavaEE 7, Primefaces 6 and Glassfish 4.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you provide a message from FireFox (where it is working). Any 'debug/console messages from Chrome/Safari?

Comment: No message. The browsers stops responding. Any idea how to get any debug message is welcome.